# Asana API: Notification for followers upon task creation

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am creating tasks through the Asana API and adding followers in the process.
The followers appear properly on the task in Asana but don't receive notification emails. If the same user is added in the Asana front-end they will receive that notification.

What am I missing?

Thanks
Manuel

Comment: Is it possible to give more detail about the problem such as steps taken to create tasks, add users and to dispatch mails? I don't know Asana but I can say that the more specific you make your question the more likely you are to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Email notifications are not triggered when followers are added to tasks via the API. I've filed this as a bug for the API team to investigate.